# near ",": syntax error - select query in sqlite3 - python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to select data from a SQLite data base using python and facing this error:

near ",": syntax error

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (
game_week TEXT NOT NULL,
hteam   TEXT,
ateam   TEXT,
gdate   TEXT, 
gtime   TEXT, 
gtvstn  TEXT
);
```

there will be unique rows for each select statement.

my code:

```
if (choice == "Y" or choice == 'y'):
        print("please enter game week, home and away team")
        gme_week = input("enter game week")
        hm_team = input("enter home team")
        aw_team = input("enter away team")

        cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE (game_week, hteam, ateam,) VALUES (?, ?, ?)''',
                    ( gme_week, hm_team, aw_team)) // this is where the code is failing                         
        try:
            row = cur.fetchone()
            print (row)
        except:
            print ("row not found! check values once and try again!")
```

I am new to python and dont really know about sqlite syntax in python.
I am using python 3.5 and sqlite3

can anyone please help me out?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is not your python code. Try your SQL Query in the [SQLite cli](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html)

Comment: Remove the comma after `ateam`, although then you will likely get another syntax error, because that doesn't look like a valid condition for a `WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct SQL-statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE game_week = ? and hteam = ? and ateam = ?
```

Comment: i tried this code according to your suggestion:


    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE game_week = ? and hteam = ? and ateam = ?)''',
                        ( gme_week, hm_team, aw_team))

and i am getting near ")" syntax error

Comment: @kpython: yes, because the `)` is not in my answer.

Comment: Ahh yes! thanks a lot Sir :)